# EF Using Inheritance for same table, only modify my entity relation, [Discriminator] column show

Tags: c#, entity-framework, class, inheritance, ef-code-first

I have a member class:

```
[Table("tMember")]
[Bind(Exclude = "TMemberType")]
public partial class tMember
{ }
```

This class does not have a relationship with the membership class, but I need that relationship. So I would create a new class and inherit from the member class like this:

```
[Table("tMember")]
public class tMemberInMembership : tMember
{
    public tMemberInMembership()
    {
        trMembership = new HashSet<trMembership>();
    }

    public virtual ICollection<trMembership> trMembership { get; set; }
}
```

but this class generates a new column, "Discriminator":

```
  FROM  [dbo].[tMember] AS [Extent1]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[trMembership] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[PersonID] = [Extent2].[PersonID]
WHERE ([Extent1].[Discriminator] = N'tMemberMembership') AND ([Extent2].[StatusMID] = '')
```

Please Help me..

Comment: what are you trying to do? if you add a class that inherits from your member class, by default, EF will implement TPH for your entity type. (see http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-inheritance-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

Comment: the sample you give me for deferent table, my problem i inheritance this class to modify this class and use it in other project. can u help me.

Comment: What kind of relationship do you mean? Inheritance, as you do now, is a "is a" relationship, but `tMemberInMembership - trMembership ` is a "has a" relationship, which shouldn't be modeled by inheritance.

Comment: the relation that i have is 'tMember - trMembership' but this relation don't have  ICollection<trMembership> so i modify the tMember table to tMember in trMembership. where this table only focusing get iColletion<trMembership>.